# WordPress gtag.js with User ID tracking

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, google-analytics

StackExchange,
I am currently creating a website and wish to implement google analytics on it. I am using the new gtag.js and also want to include user id tracking. I've had a little python experience but almost no PHP experience. I have looked through stack overflow and a couple of other places and have come up with this site-specific plugin - is this the most efficient (or even will it work) way of doing it?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Analytics Suite
Plugin URI: -redacted-
Description: Implements Google Analytics using the new gtag.js and combining user id.
Author: -redacted-
Version: 1.0
*/
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
 $user = wp_get_current_user();
 $userName = $user->user_login;
}
function ns_google_analytics() { ?>
 <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXXXXXX"></script>
      <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX', {
            'user_id': '1'
        });
      </script>
 <?php if (isset($userName)) : ?>
      <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX', {
            'user_id': '1'
        });
      </script>  
 <?php else : ?>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'XXXXXXXXXXX');
    </script> 
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php
 }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'ns_google_analytics', 10 );
```

Thank you in advance, Piklet.

The person who posted below is correct, but I posted as a guest and can't get into that account to mark it as a solution. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do a couple of things:

- Move your calls to get the user inside your function - PHP variables aren't shared across scopes without using `global`, which is generally a bad idea because it pollutes the global scope
- Consolidate your JS
- Use escaping methods before outputting data

With those in mind, I think this might work for you:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Analytics Suite
 * Plugin URI: -redacted-
 * Description: Implements Google Analytics using the new gtag.js and combining user id.
 * Author: -redacted-
 * Version: 1.0
 */
function ns_google_analytics() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
?>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX"></script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
<?php if ( 0 !== $user->ID ) : ?>
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX', {
        'user_id': '<?php echo esc_js( $user->user_login ); ?>'
    });
<?php else : ?>
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXX');
<?php endif; ?>
    </script>
 <?php
 }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'ns_google_analytics', 10 );
```

In the above code:

- We get the user outright using `wp_get_current_user`. From the [WordPress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) (*Emphasis mine*):

  > WP_User object where it can be retrieved using member variables. **Attribute ID will show 0 if there is no user.**
- This means you will always get a `\WP_User` back, and you can check if the `ID` is zero to determine if a user is logged in or not.
- Your conditional `if` statement really only needs to output specific JS in one spot, so those areas are consolidated
- All output should be escaped, hence the use of [`esc_js`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_js)